# GitHub в Visual Studio Com 2019. Проблема с логином

Tags: visual-studio, github

Проблема с логирование на GitHub в Visual Studio Community 2019 Preview. С аккаунтом все хорошо, захожу на него через браузер. Пробовал на работе заходить через Visual Studio Community 2019 - работает норм.

Дома вечная ошибка весит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На кнопки перезайти или выйте не реагирует. При нажатие ничего не происходит.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же есть еще это окно, оно так же не реагирует на логин или открыть через браузер

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что самое интересное, сам Git работает нормально, могу комитеть, а вот через студию уже смотреть весь функционал, например историю комитов уже не могу, требует логин. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Слово proxy в сообщении об ошибке как-бы подсказывает.

Comment: Я как бы согласен, но реально не знаю что делать, можете подсказать где какие настройки изменить?

Comment: Поискать что-то похожее на network,  proxy  и посмотреть что там записано.

Comment: @Эникейщик Все настройки с прокси проверял, никак паталогий не было выявлено. Даже не знаю что делать